# check_win_release || Connection timed out after

Tags: r, curl, connection, devtools, cran

I'm interested to check if my package is compatible with the windows platform. The library was developed on debian system `Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)`. In order to check windows' comparability I run  `devtools::check_win_release()` which leads me to errors with connection time out:

It first asks for email confirmation to which I confirm.

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) :
  Timeout was reached: [win-builder.r-project.org] Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
```

I spoke to the IT admin and they have set a firewall for security measures and forbid interaction via curl or any other utilities. I've proxy settings set as suggested by the IT-admin but again they are in vain.

Is there any way I can check windows build?

I've tried  `options(timeout = 4000000)` but the error persists.

`R 4.0` `devtools_2.3.1` `testthat_2.3.2`

There is no `build_win`

I'm using http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/release.html as my resource.

Edit:  `Sys.getenv("http_proxy")` and  `Sys.getenv("https_proxy")` print the proxy settings set in the bash environment variable.

Comment: `check_win_release` is uploading the package to `win-builder.r-project.org`, which means that it is trying to connect to your database from the internet. If your testing database is not internet-visible, then this will not work.

Comment: Since `devtools` is using the `curl` package to upload the package, I wonder if `curl` is auto-detecting your proxy information correctly. Does `curl::ie_proxy_info()` find things correctly? (Sorry, not sure if/how it's working, I don't have a proxy configured for it to detect.)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. `curl::ie_proxy_info()` gives me `NULL`

Comment: yeah, that could indicate that `curl` is not finding a system-wide proxy setting. I don't know how to do that with `curl` on non-windows platforms, sorry. (The `ie_` in the function name did not fill me with confidence for non-windows.)

Comment: I see. Although system-wide settings aren't fetched, I can get the proxy settings within the R environment. Please see my edited post for `Sys.getenv`.

Comment: I just saw that, that seems the best way to influence `libcurl`'s proxy determination. No more ideas atm.

Comment: @r2evans - an update - I moved package to windows machine to perform the checks. No other way I could find. rhub::check_on_* has multiple options :)